# What is the point of defining a property that looks like below? What it brings in the context of hermetization?

Tags: c#, properties

I read a lot about properties and encapsulation but I don't understand when should I use shortened code entry for properties and when I can use properties for in practice.

Bellow are some examples of property and variable definition which I found and modified. I think, I understand correctly how each of them works, but I do not see the point of using some of them in practise.

```
class MyClass
    {
        //1 - read and write property short record
        public string Name1 { get; set; } = "Name1 content";

        //2 - variable instead of property from 1 ex.
        public string Name2 = "Name2 content";

        //3 - read and write property long record
        private string _name3 = default(string);
        public string Name3
        {
            get => _name3;
            set => _name3 = value;
        }

        //4 - read and write property with checking of value
        private string _name4 = default(string);
        public string Name4
        {
            get
            {
                return _name4;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length >= 3)
                    _name4 = value;
            }
        }

        //5 - read only property short record
        public string Name5 { get; } = "Name5 content";

        //6 - read only variable
        public static readonly string Name6 = "Name6 content";

        //7 - read (public) and write (in class range) property
        private string _name7 = default(string);

        public MyClass(string n)
        {
            this._name7 = n;
        }

        public string Name7
        {
            get => _name4;
            private set => _name7 = value;
        }
    }
```

Ex. 1 What is the advantage of declaring properties, exactly like this, instead of a variable (Ex. 2)? I know, that properties can be use in interfaces as opposed to fields (variables), but, is there any other advantage?

Ex. 3 makes no sense to me, but it is presented in most examples of the application of properties. It doesn't provide (in my opinion) encapsulation of 
_name3, because every change of Name3 (from outside) causes change of _name3 (in MyClass)

Ex. 4 makes sense to me.  But are the properties used in practice only to check the input conditions? It can be done in constructors.

Ex. 5 and Ex. 6 are similar to Ex. 1 and Ex. 2. If I want to block the possibility of changing the value of Name5 I cas use readonly variable instead of property (as in Ex. 6).

Ex. 7 is the only example of use of properties to encapsulation I found and modified. _name7/Name7 is possible to set from outside only by constructor. Then I can change it only from MyClass.

Could you, apart from the answer to my doubts, give me some examples of the most common practical use of properties?

Comment: Those you commented as 'variables' are actually fields and `_name7` is also a field (not a property)

Comment: Properties define the behavior of a class, fields are its implementation. By creating a property you say "hey, I am a Brush, which can have a color". It may be an auto-property, property with backing field or something else, but this is all hidden behind the abstraction and lets you change the implementation at any time. It also lets child classes to override this implementation without breaking the contract. That's in short...

Comment: vc 74 - I agree that _name7 is a variable. I commented this part as "property" due to Name7 (_name7 is only auxiliary variable). I don't understand why other variables beginning with a capital "N" you say they are fields. For me variables in class = fields but the properties are not.